# unlink() from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Don't know much about running a function on every item in an array, still pretty new to PHP, below `$pic_loc` is a data array from MySQL containing the path and filename to images matching whatever search criteria is preformed.

Tried to get the `unlink` function to run on everyone that it found. No errors return. I don't think `foreach` is the proper way to go, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 $pic_loc = $cell_pictures['pic_loc']; //gathers an array from the database of files locations

    $pics_to_delete .= "../../".$pic_loc; //corrects the directory

    foreach($pics_to_delete as $pics_being_deleted) //deletes all pictures found
    {

    unlink($pics_being_deleted);

    }
```

EDIT:
I tinkered with it alot with both answers, I know I can delete files 2 tiers up because i can do it for individual files with no problem. This is what I'm currently doing, i got rid of the `while()` loop figuring maybe that was causing an issue for the foreach to function:

```
$data_array2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE user_id = '".$id."'");
$cell_pictures = mysql_fetch_array($data_array2);


foreach($cell_pictures['pic_loc'] as $pics_being_deleted) //deletes all pictures found
{

unlink("../../".$pics_being_deleted);

}
```

here's the error it returns now:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() // on the line that the foreach is on
```

EDIT:
Ok that was screwy, BUT I GOT IT!!! you would think that the data coming from the query would've been an array, but no you actually had to set it as an array. This is how I did it:

```
$data_array2 = mysql_query("SELECT pic_loc FROM pictures WHERE user_id = '".$id."'");


while($cell_pictures = mysql_fetch_array($data_array2))
{
$the_pics = $cell_pictures['pic_loc'];
$pics_as_array = array($the_pics);
}

foreach($pics_as_array as $pics_being_deleted) 
{

unlink("../../".$pics_being_deleted);


}
```

This works excellent. Thanks a whole bunch for taking the time to read this!
-Mike

Comment: There's an `array_walk` function, but foreach isn't so bad too.

Comment: @user1053263 So what's the problem? Pics aren't deleted?

Comment: it seems $pics_to_delete is a string, not an array that you could foreach thru. If you want to get an array of all files in a directory, use `scandir` function.

Comment: @ozzy, yeah the pics aren't deleting and John, I just assumed it's an array because I use mysql_fetch_array() to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $cell_pictures['pic_loc'] is an array of files to be deleted then

```
foreach($cell_pictures['pic_loc'] as $pics_being_deleted) //deletes all pictures found
{

unlink("../../".$pics_being_deleted);

}
```

Comment: $file=$cell_pictures['pic_loc']; 
foreach($file as $pics_being_deleted). Try this in your edited code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `foreach` is perfectly alright for what you want do.

However, you need to put some of your logic inside the *iteration*. Let's see:

```
$directory = realpath("../../"); // the directory where files are placed
foreach ($pics_to_delete as $basename) //deletes all pictures found
{
    $path = sprtinf('%s/%s', $directory, $basename);
    unlink($path);
}
```

A better option is to do it the other way round. First get the directory and all files therein, then filter that list against the files to delete. Only if the names match, proceed:

```
$dir = new  DirectoryIterator($path);
$toDelete = new DeleteFilter($dir, $pics_to_delete);
foreach ($toDelete as $file)
{
    printf("Delete: %s\n", $file->getPathname());
    unlink($file->getPathname());
}
```

The `DirectoryIterator` ships with PHP, the `DeleteFilter` is a small `FilterIterator` that ensures only real files matching and entry from the `$pics_to_delete` array will be returned:

```
class DeleteFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    private $filenames;

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, array $filenames)
    {
        $this->filenames = $filenames;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        if (!($current instanceof SplFileInfo)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (!$current->isFile()) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return in_array($current->getBasename(), $this->filenames);
    }
}
```

You don't need that filter iterator, instead you can write that logic inside the `foreach`, however I think this one is more fluent.

Comment: I'm going to try your second option

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this! The second option works! I just couldn't use it because I figure it scanning the directory would be more of a pull on the HD.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the web host settings are that you do not have permission to delete or access any file which is a folder higher than you are. In your case, you're going two folders up.

You may need to restructure your program so that pics are stored below the file which is trying to delete them.

In addition, make sure you are passing the correct filename string to unlink. If you're not sure, you can echo the filename for testing.